# Using Regex to search for a string and add a class to that string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying to search my html for a string pattern `/fox/` and add a class to that string `.orange`.

```
var fox = /fox/;

fox.addClass(".orange");
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rourkemclaren/dw2cdf6e/6/)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Its confusing, DO you only wish to search for fox?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm trying to: 1. search my html text for a specific string. 2. somehow store and add a class to that string.

Comment: You can use the :contains() selector -- https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ -- but this uses strings, not regex

Comment: You can not add class to some word, so if in your text exist "fox" you can add class to his parent (<p> or <div> or ...)

Comment: What is your specific string?

Comment: @Explosion Pills - I'm not married to regex, happy to use anything that works. :contains() allows me to add a class to the div but not a word inside the div.

Comment: @XOR-Manik, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' - check my jsfiddle

Comment: Seems like this might help you? http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: @ErmineSoft could I convert the string to an element then?

Comment: Ya I saw that, but sorry I still did not understand, what do you want to extract.

Comment: I'd like the script to scan any sentence and identify a certain word, for example 'fox' and allow me to add a styling class to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I get this right, but a quick way to do this would be

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
Array.from(a).forEach(val => {
    val.innerHTML = val.innerHTML.replace(/fox/,'<span class="orange">fox</span>');
})
```

Without `Array.from()` as it isn't supported in many browsers for now:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    [].slice.call(a).forEach(val => {
        val.innerHTML = val.innerHTML.replace(/fox/,'<span class="orange">fox</span>');
    })
```

Comment: Just be careful with the phrase you are using. If it exists anywhere else in the html it is going to be replaced by <span class="orange">fox</span>. For example if you set an element with the class="fox" the class will be changed to class="<span class="orange"></span>"  see fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/ta328aey/

Comment: In the case that it is in the innerHTML of one of the `p`, yes... I hope it's okay for OP

Comment: is it going to be a static keyword or will the user be entering the keyword to search?